# Rails ActiveRecord - find by substring of another string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
id | name
1  | jack
2  | tomas
```

I want to find a row if the name is a substring of `Ttomas`.
So the result should be

```
id | name
2  | tomas
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in Ruby on Rails and SQL. Depends a bit on the database you use, but something like this should work:

```
Modelname.where("? LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')", 'Ttomas')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

The brute-force way would be to iterate through all your users and check if `name` is a substring. But this horribly inefficient.

If you want to utilize SQL lookups, you need to look into gems like [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) or [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby) for full search functionality.